# Using spy and Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have the following function

```
function trim(value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    if (String.prototype.trim) {
      value = value.trim();
    } else {
      value = value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

I am writing a unit test for it to ensure that when `trim` is called native `String.prototype.trim` is called if available. I am trying to use spy to ensure that it is called

```
var Util = require('test/util/methods');

it('should use native trim', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(String.prototype, 'trim');
    Util.trim('test string   ');
    expect(spy.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    expect(Util.trim('test string    ')).toEqual('test string');
    spy.restore();
  });
```

But what I feel I should be doing is that when `trim` is called I should be checking that `String.prototype.trim` is called also.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the function is called and `String.prototype.trim` is called also"?  You are calling the function in the test, so that is obviously called, no?  Do you mean you want to test the non-native implementation?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I just want to check that `String.prototype.trim` is called (if it is available), which is what i am doing now (spying on `String.prototype.trim`). but what if i want to spy on `trim` and ensure that `String.prototype.trim` is called afterwards ? Does that make sense ?

Comment: IMO, building order of execution into unit tests is not always a good idea.  It makes the tests quite brittle when things change later.  However, I still don't quite understand.  You want to see if `Util.trim` is called before `String.prototype.trim`?

Comment: im probably over complicating it then, but the answer below seems fine, thanks for at least getting involved, appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So call `trim` only once, and then have your two `expect`s:

```
it('should use native trim', function() {
    var spy = sinon.spy(String.prototype, 'trim');
    expect(Util.trim('test string    ')).toEqual('test string');
    expect(spy.calledOnce).toEqual(true);
    spy.restore();
});
```